# Can someone help me put this download code that I use in ASyncTask?

Tags: android

It works just fine when I run it in a thread, but I want to use Asynctask and when I execute my version of it, nothing happens:

```
try {
  //set the download URL, a url that points to a file on the internet
  //this is the file to be downloaded
  URL url = new URL(filename2);

  //create the new connection
  HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

  //set up some things on the connection
  urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
  urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

  //and connect!
  urlConnection.connect();

  //set the path where we want to save the file
  //in this case, going to save it on the root directory of the
  //sd card.
  SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/";
  //create a new file, specifying the path, and the filename
  //which we want to save the file as.
  File file = new File(SDCardRoot,filename3);

  //this will be used to write the downloaded data into the file we created
  FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);

  //this will be used in reading the data from the internet
  InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

  //this is the total size of the file
  //int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
  //variable to store total downloaded bytes
  int downloadedSize = 0;

  //create a buffer...
  byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
  int bufferLength = 0; //used to store a temporary size of the buffer

  //now, read through the input buffer and write the contents to the file
  while ((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    //add the data in the buffer to the file in the file output stream (the file on the sd card
    fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
    //add up the size so we know how much is downloaded
    downloadedSize += bufferLength;
    //this is where you would do something to report the prgress, like this maybe
    //updateProgress(downloadedSize, totalSize);
    //publishProgress((int)(total*100/lenghtOfFile));
  }

  //close the output stream when done
  fileOutput.close();
//catch some possible errors...
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {             
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {               
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

THIS IS MY ATTEMPT AS REQUESTED:

```
      private class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Long> {
       protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
        Intent in = new Intent(mainmenu.this, DownloadService.class);           
        stopService(in);

    }

    @Override
    protected Long doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {

            //set the download URL, a url that points to a file on the internet
            //this is the file to be downloaded
            URL url = new URL(filename2);


            //create the new connection
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            //set up some things on the connection
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            //and connect!
            urlConnection.connect();

            //set the path where we want to save the file
            //in this case, going to save it on the root directory of the
            //sd card.
            SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/";
            //create a new file, specifying the path, and the filename
            //which we want to save the file as.
            File file = new File(SDCardRoot,filename3);

            //this will be used to write the downloaded data into the file we created
            FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);

            //this will be used in reading the data from the internet
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            //this is the total size of the file
            //int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
            //variable to store total downloaded bytes
            int downloadedSize = 0;

            //create a buffer...
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bufferLength = 0; //used to store a temporary size of the buffer

            //now, read through the input buffer and write the contents to the file
            while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
                    //add the data in the buffer to the file in the file output stream (the file on the sd card
                    fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                    //add up the size so we know how much is downloaded
                    downloadedSize += bufferLength;
                    //this is where you would do something to report the prgress, like this maybe
                    //updateProgress(downloadedSize, totalSize);
                    //publishProgress((int)(total*100/lenghtOfFile));


            }
            //close the output stream when done
            fileOutput.close();





    //catch some possible errors...
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {             
            e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {               
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
        return null;
    }


}
```

Comment: How are you trying to use it in the AsyncTask? Paste your code.

Comment: well it doesn't work so there is no point. i just need this to go in the do in background method and then i think execute like this: new DownloadFile().execute(); because filename2 is getting passed into it already.

Comment: How do you know the code is not being executed? Have you already use the debugger to check whether AsyncTask is being called. It looks fine.

Comment: onpreexecute launches a service with a notification and that never happens. the song is also never downloaded. =/ am i executing it right with newDownloadFile().execute(); it is being executed under my shouldoverrideurlloading when a url is an mp3

Comment: Yes, but how do you know it is not even getting into doInBackground? What have you done to check that? Have you at least used `Log` class or check the logtrace to see if an exception is occurring?

Comment: I am afraid I don't know how to use log. I usually test by sending an apk to my phone. I don't know what kind of exception would be occurring though.

Comment: http://www.droidnova.com/debugging-in-android-using-eclipse,541.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you go

```
public class WebRequest extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, String> {
ProgressDialog dialog;
Context _context;

String _title;
String _message;

public WebRequest(Context context, 
        String ProgressTitle, String ProgressMessage) {
    this._context = context;

    this._title = ProgressTitle;
    this._message = ProgressMessage;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(_context);
    dialog.setTitle(_title);
    dialog.setMessage(_message);
    dialog.show();

}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(URL... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try {

        //set the download URL, a url that points to a file on the internet
        //this is the file to be downloaded
        URL url = params[0];


        //create the new connection
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        //set up some things on the connection
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

        //and connect!
        urlConnection.connect();

        //set the path where we want to save the file
        //in this case, going to save it on the root directory of the
        //sd card.
        SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/";
        //create a new file, specifying the path, and the filename
        //which we want to save the file as.
        File file = new File(SDCardRoot,filename3);

        //this will be used to write the downloaded data into the file we created
        FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);

        //this will be used in reading the data from the internet
        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        //this is the total size of the file
        //int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
        //variable to store total downloaded bytes
        int downloadedSize = 0;

        //create a buffer...
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bufferLength = 0; //used to store a temporary size of the buffer

        //now, read through the input buffer and write the contents to the file
        while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
                //add the data in the buffer to the file in the file output stream (the     file on the sd card
                fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                //add up the size so we know how much is downloaded
                downloadedSize += bufferLength;
                //this is where you would do something to report the prgress, like this maybe
                //updateProgress(downloadedSize, totalSize);
                //publishProgress((int)(total*100/lenghtOfFile));


        }
        //close the output stream when done
        fileOutput.close();

       return "Success";



//catch some possible errors...
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {             
        e.printStackTrace();
    return "Failed";
} catch (IOException e) {               
        e.printStackTrace();
           return "Failed";
}
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (dialog.isShowing())
        dialog.cancel();

    Toast.makeText(_context,result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

}

}
```

//using this

```
 WebRequest request = new WebRequest(context,"Downloading","Please wait..");
 request.Execute(object of URL);
```

Comment: Getting an error on context here:  WebRequest request = new WebRequest(context,"Downloading","Please wait..");

Comment: you will have to pass a context, which should be your activity name .. like lets say your activity name is MyActivity then pass , MyActivity.this as context

Comment: by object of URL do you mean a variable of type URL, because nothing is happening still..

Comment: the dialog pops up and says Downloading then disappears right away

Comment: have you given the "android.permission.INTERNET" permission in manifest? also if progress dialog appears then Async task is executing.. but if no toast is displayed then it could be the code in doInBackground is doing something funny..

Comment: Oh my of course I had internet permissions on....... but I forgot to add WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE now the file downloaded. Thank you, you were helpful and dedicated.